# android tts hindi locale

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am building a `tts` app using the `google tts` libraries. when I set the language `locale` to hindi and get back to app it doesn't say the text correctly. I have to `restart` the app for it to speak hindi correctly.

```
t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            }
        }
    });

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak = ed1.getText().toString().trim();
            t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Passing null as the parameters and not setting a progress or utterance listener can cause problems. Also, use some logging to output the current language of the tts before you speak().

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for hindi tts use. that code work for me.

```
public class AndroidTextToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements
    TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
private TextToSpeech tts;
private Button btnSpeak;
private EditText txtText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

    txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

    // button on click event
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            speakOut();
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(new Locale("hi"));
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
        } else {
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
            speakOut();
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }

}

private void speakOut() {
    String text = txtText.getText().toString();
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

}
}
```